# vb.net For Each loop

Tags: vb.net, list, for-loop

I would like to loop through two lists using a For each loop.

```
dim data as list(of pointpairlist)
For each recLine in records
    For Each chan In recLine.channels and d in data
      d.add( func(chan) )
    Next
next
```

note: each record line has one sample from each channel recorded. ie each record line is a slice of a 32 sensor recordings. I want to build up a x,y list of data points for each channel (the x axis is common to all channels)

Is there some way to do it similar to what i have above (avoiding indexing variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to iterate over two different collections in a single loop is to use indexers.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To recLine.channels.Count - 1
    data(index) = func(chan(index))
Next
```

As @0xA3 comments, you can also a while loop, calling `GetEnumerator`, `MoveNext` and `Current` directly on each collection, but this buys you nothing.

I realize you want to avoid using indexers, but there is no simple language support for anything else.

This is the case also for C#.

Why do you need to avoid indexers?

Comment: Well, you *could* use a while loop and call `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` and `Current` yourself, if you really want to avoid an indexer. This should work well if the lists have the same size but it doesn't really give you an advantage.

Comment: well, it was a mix of trying to have less clutter, and knowing that I really don't know all the constructs in vb.net that well. I typically code in vb.net as if it was C or C++ which is probably not the most efficient use of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Nest the loops.  I cannot reverse-engineer the actual declarations from the snippet, but something like this:

```
    Dim data As List(Of PointPairList)
    ''...
    For Each point In data
        For Each chan In point.recLine
            func(chan)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: doesn't quite work because each "point" is actually a list of points populated by each channel (a points list for each channel list).

But know i realize i left something out. I will edit the question

Comment: Well, something like that.  Seems you've adopted the nested loop approach.  Why did you select an answer that doesn't use it?

Comment: Cause thats what I ended up using! :)